# Bare-NP Adverbs in German

Tags: german, lexicon, adverbs

There is a special class of noun phrases in English that have the ability to function as adverbial modifiers, unaccompanied by a preposition or any other indicator of adjunct status. These are the so-called bare-NP adverbs. Here are some examples:

```
(1) I saw John [that day].
(2) I saw John [someplace you'd never guess].
(3) John was headed [that way].
(4) Max pronounced my name [every way imaginable].
```

As I was wondering if there is similar phenomenon in German, a sentence came to my mind:

```
(5) Eines Tages geht er auf der Straße spazieren.
```

Can "Eines Tages" here be regarded as a bare-NP adverb? Are there other similar examples in German?

Comment: [1995] fuhr ich nach Berlin. Mein Bleiben dort dauerte [zwei Tage]. [Jeder Tag] spazirte ich durch die Stadt.

Comment: That is helpful. What cases are they assigned, by the way?

Comment: All of them are in Nominativ. Your 'eines Tages' is Genitiv.

Comment: The case in _1995_ is ambiguous. _Jeder Tag spazierte ich durch die Stadt_ is ungrammatical; it should be _Jeden Tag …_ (accusative). In the second sentence, _zwei Tage_ is also accusative, as can be seen by replacing it with _einen Tag_; however in this case, it serves as an object, so it isn‘t an adverb.

Comment: Thank you @chirlu. So is it safe to draw a conclusion that bare-NP adverbs in German are in accusative case with the exception of "eines Tages"?

Comment: There are more examples of adverbial genitives, including ones unrelated to time; e.g. _meines Wissens_ (‘as far as I know’). You may be interested in this question on German.SE: [Traditional grammar on “noun-centered” phrases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26053)

Comment: The Duden deals briefly with the new orthography, [see D 70, 71](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K67).70    teilnehmen, ich nehme an der Veranstaltung teil
    Aber
    Anteil nehmen, ich nehme am Vorfall Anteil
    maßhalten oder Maß halten,
    ich halte maß oder Maß